# How can I set Vim to switch to a buffer after I add it?

Tags: buffers

**TLDR: Can I make Vim automatically switch to the buffer that I just opened?**

Please tell me if I'm using Vim wrong in this case or something.

I'm currently working with `foo.txt`.  I want to look at `bar.txt`.  I type `:badd bar.txt`.  I now have a new buffer for `bar.txt`, but I'm still looking at `foo.txt`, and I'm annoyed that Vim didn't switch to `bar.txt`.

The thing I just opened should be the focus, not put in the background.  It seems like every other piece of software acts differently.  I use `set hidden`, so it shouldn't matter if I have unsaved changes in `foo.txt`.

Comment: `:e bar.txt` opens bar.txt and switch to the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:edit` or `:e` to edit a file:

```
:e bar.txt
```

`:badd` will simply add the buffer/document to the buffer list and not focus the buffer like you want.

For more help see:

```
:h :e
:h :badd
:h buffers
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I bet I learned that from vimtutor, but forgot.  No wonder I couldn't find the answer on Google; `edit`ing is different than `badd`ing.